# How to work around expensive custom hooks?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

As we know, the rule is:

> Only Call Hooks at the Top Level. Don’t call Hooks inside loops, conditions, or nested functions.

So my questions is how to use and design a custom hook that is expensive?

Given this hook:

```
const useExpensiveHook = () => {
    // some code that uses other built-in hooks...
    const value = computeExpensiveValue();
    // some more code....
    return value;
}
```

If that rule did not exist my client code would be:

```
const myComponent = ({isSuperFeatureEnabled}) => {
   let value;
   if (isSuperFeatureEnabled){
      value = useExpensiveHook();
   }

   return <div>{value}</div>;
}
```

The solution I came up with is to let the hook know that it should bail out, like this, using a flag:

```
const useExpensiveHook = ({enabled}) => {
    // some code that uses other built-in hooks...
    let value;
      if(enabled) {
          value = computeExpensiveValue();
      }
      else {
          value = undefined;
      }
    // some more code....
    return value;
};
```

and the client code:

```
const myComponent = ({isSuperFeatureEnabled}) => {
   const value = useExpensiveHook({enabled : isSuperFeatureEnabled});
   return <div>{value}</div>;
}
```

It is passing a flag to expensive hooks the right way to handle conditional hooks? What are the other options?

Comment: Have you looked into `useMemo` or `useCallback` for the expensive computation? https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usememo

Comment: `computeExpensiveValue()` would be called at least once with those. right? Here I need to avoid the call completely.

Comment: Yea, that's true. Hmm, couldn't you just do the `if (enabled)` inside the `computeExpensiveValue` function? This way you could do `const expensiveValue = useCallback(() => computeExpensiveValue, [enabled]);`

Comment: Yes I could, but that wouldn't change the custom hook external api; the client code would still have to pass in a flag.

Comment: What is hook supposed to do? How should it work when it's disabled? Notice that in your example it's initial value that is expensive.

Comment: I updated the code to make it more abstract. In the previous code I used `useState` to illustrate the problem. But it led some of you into thinking that my issue is specific to `useState`, but it's not. This is a generic question about expensive hooks, not a question specific to this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In original example it is hook initial value that is expensive, not a hook itself, `computeExpensiveValue` can be conditionally called:

```
const [value, setValue] = useState(enabled ? computeExpensiveValue() : undefined);
```

In currently listed example `useExpensiveHook` is not a hook but some function; it doesn't use React hooks.

The purpose of quoted rule is to make built-in hooks called unconditionally because the state of hooks is determined by the order in which they are called:

```
if (flipCoin())
  var [foo] = useState('foo');

var [bar] = useState('bar');
```

In case `useState('foo')` isn't called on next component render, `useState('bar')` becomes the first `useState` hook to be called and considered `foo` state, while second `useState` is missing, this inconsistency triggers an error in a renderer.

If it were guaranteed that the order of hook calls is preserved, it would be acceptable to use conditions but this is rarely feasible in practice. Even if there's seemingly constant condition like `if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development')`, it could change under some circumstances at runtime and result in said problems that are hard to debug.

Correct:

```
useEffect(() => {
  if (varyingCondition)
    computeExpensiveValue();
});
```

Incorrect:

```
if (varyingCondition)
  useEffect(() => {
    computeExpensiveValue();
  });
```

This rule applies only to built-in hooks and functions that call them directly or indirectly (so-called custom hooks). As long as `computeExpensiveValue` doesn't use built-in hooks internally, it can be conditionally called, as 'correct' example shows.

In case a component needs to conditionally apply third-party hook depending on prop flag, it should be guaranteed that the condition won't change with time by restricting it to be initial prop value:

```
const Component = ({ expensive, optionalValue }) => {
  const isExpensive = useMemo(() => expensive, []);
  if (isExpensive)
    optionalValue = useExpensiveHook();
  return ...
}
```

This way `<Component expensive={flipCoin()} />` won't break the rule but just misuse the component.

Since it should be known if expensive hook is needed at the time when `<Component expensive/>` is used, a cleaner way is to compose this functionality in higher-order component and use different components depending on which one is needed:

```
const withExpensive = Comp => props => {
  const optionalValue = useExpensiveHook();
  return <Comp optionalValue={optionalValue} ...props />;
}

const Component = ({ optionalValue }) => {
  return ...
}

const ExpensiveComponent = withExpensive(Component);
```

Comment: I'm sorry if my example made you think that the issue is specific to `useState`. I've updated the question to make it more abstract. The question is : is using a flags like this the right pattern?

Comment: Yes, flags are ok. After the last edit useExpensiveHook  isn't a hook anymore, just a helper function. Custom hook is a function that uses built-in hooks in some way.

Comment: Well you have to pretend that the code `// some code that uses other hooks...` makes `useExpensiveHook ` a real hook. Otherwise the question is no longer valid.

Comment: Yes, it wasn't obvious that 'hooks' refers to built-in hooks. The answers sums it up. If there's a little chance that condition may change during component lifespan, don't apply a condition to a hook and apply it to computeExpensiveValue. But the way hook should be written depends on the case. It's unknown why there is `enabled` condition, why computeExpensiveValue is optional and how it interacts with hooks. Do you have some specific case in mind?

Comment: The `enabled` flag should not be there at all. If the expensive custom hook were provided by a 3rd party, then I'd have to way of not invoking it. Adding the `enabled` flag to the hook interface is just an escape hatch. I'd rather have a better solution that only involves code in the client code; not the hook code.

Comment: We have one case here where the costly part is that the custom hook will subscribe to a data source and be woken up each time the source changes. But that's totally useless in the case where the client doesn't even need the hook at all (when `isSuperFeatureEnabled` is `false`).

Comment: Couldn't a hook with subscription and without be two different hooks? I don't think anything else can be suggested for general case. Yes, there should be a condition somewhere. There can be better approaches for specific case but this is possibly a question for http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ and not SO.

Comment: I'm afraid I'm not making myself clear. If a hook called `useStackoverflowFeed` existed and was provided by a 3rd party. Then how would my client component code only invoke that hook when it's own `isSuperFeatureEnabled` prop is set to `true`?

Comment: So your computeExpensiveValue is actually a hook, useStackoverflowFeed, isn't it? Then it can be called conditionally the same way. As long as the condition is definite (the value of isSuperFeatureEnabled param), you're safe from problems that *the rule* is supposed to prevent.

Comment: No, `useStackoverflowFeed` replaces `useExpensiveHook` in the above example.

Comment: So it is `if (props.enabled) useExpensiveHook()`, correct? It doesn't look good, a prop can change with time. A cleaner way to secure the rule would be to just have different component versions with and without feed subscription, e.g. with a HOC, `const MyFeedComponent = withFeed(MyComponent)`.

Comment: Yes that is correct, that's what the first code spinet illustrates in the question. I'd want to call `useExpensiveHook()` conditionally, but I can't because of the hooks rules. And yes, your solution would work if the code that calls the hook is in a component.

Comment: I updated the answer for completeness. Hope this clarifies the case.

Comment: I like the use of `const isExpensive = useMemo(() => expensive, []);` to make sure the condition becomes _stable_.

Answer (score 0):

The argument to `useState` is being used only once and hence if you initially pass `enabled` as false to it, it will not execute the `computeExpensiveValue` ever. Hence you would need to add a `useEffect` call too. You could instead design your hook like

```
const useExpensiveHook = ({enabled}) => {
    const [value, setValue] = useState(enabled ? computeExpensiveValue : undefined);

    useEffect(()=> {
      if(enabled) {
          const value = computeExpensiveValue();
          setValue(value);
      }
    }, [enabled]);

    // some more code.... 
    return value;
};
```

Comment: I'm sorry if my example made you think that the issue is specific to `useState`. I've updated the question to make it more abstract. The question is : is using a flags like this the right pattern?

Comment: @Sylvain why would you have an expensive computation in a custom hook? Why not use a memoized function or useMemo. Also just like you take a decision to compute expensive logic in a component using a flag, you can do so with hooks too and a flag implementation would look similar to the answer I wrote above

Comment: I don't like my design where a hook has to receive a flag to bail out. The real need here is for the client to not invoke the hook if it does not need it, but the hook rules forbid that. Accepting a flag in the hook is not elegant. I just can't find a better idea.

Comment: I'm looking at this from a theoretical standpoint. If a hook is expensive, how do you prevent it from running? We have one case here where the costly part is that the custom hook will subscribe to a data source and be woken up each time the source changes. But that's totally useless in the case where the client doesn't even need the hook at all (when isSuperFeatureEnabled is false).

Comment: Its perfectly alright to write a custom hook that uses useState and useEffect and not to use them based on a condition. Much like you would do in component lifecycle. One more thing you can do is to take out your logic in a separate component which has the computation hooks and render this component conditionally if thats possible