# React hooks: activable states patterns

Tags: reactjs, design-patterns, react-hooks

I'm trying to create a component that can activate/disable some functionality depending on the props. All of those functions will need a state that has to be managed.

I was trying to think to a possible pattern that would permit us not to create the state in case the connected functionality is not active. I thought to 2 possible way to do that:

WAY #1

```
function useFunctionality(initState, enable) {
    if (!enable) {
        return null;
    }

    const [funct, updateFunct] = useState(init);
    return funct;
}

function Component({ enableFunct }) {
    const funct = useFunctionality('test', enableFunct);
    return (...);
}
```

WAY #2

```
function useFunctionality(initState, enable) {
    const [funct, updateFunct] = useState(init);
    return enable ? funct : null;
}

function Component({ enableFunct }) {
    const funct = useFunctionality('test', enableFunct);
    return (...);
}
```

In both ways, hooks keep working. The question is: which way do you feel more correct? There is a better way to do this?

Comment: I would suggest `useReducer` with a reducer that can handle all the states rather than `useState` for each functionality. You could potentially build the reducer dynamically, based on the props if necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both recipes have problems.

Way 1 potentially allows to call a hook conditionally on component render, this may result in error ans is [discouraged](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html#only-call-hooks-at-the-top-level):

> Don’t call Hooks inside loops, conditions, or nested functions. Instead, always use Hooks at the top level of your React function. By following this rule, you ensure that Hooks are called in the same order each time a component renders. That’s what allows React to correctly preserve the state of Hooks between multiple useState and useEffect calls.

As explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54810108/3731501), this rule can be discarded, as long as it's guaranteed that a condition doesn't change between renders.

A way to guarantee this is to memoize a condition:

```
function useFunctionality(initState, enable) {
    const condition = useMemo(() => enable, []);

    if (!condition)
        return null;

    const [funct, updateFunct] = useState(initState);
    return funct;
}
```

Way 2 is more preferable because it's cleaner and `useState` call isn't expensive.

Both ways have the same problem, they use a state that never changes. If this is the intention, that's a use case for a ref. Since it never changes, a condition can be placed as initial value:

```
function useFunctionality(initState, enable) {
    return useRef(enable ? initState: null).current;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to disable usage of a particular functionality based on props, a better way is to not execute the functionality instead of executing the entire logic and returning null or undefined because we didn't need the response. So the first approach is a better one

```
function useFunctionality(initState, enable) {
    if (!enable) {
        return null;
    }

    const [funct, updateFunct] = useState(init);
    return funct;
}

function Component({ enableFunct }) {
    const funct = useFunctionality('test', enableFunct);
    return (...);
}
```

This might be particularly important when the computation inside custom hooks is expensive.

Comment: This is actually the scenario the documentation warns against, https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html#only-call-hooks-at-the-top-level . `enableFunct` value may change between renders.

Comment: True, but actually as the enable variable or is true or is false (cannot never change) wouldn't the state always been in the first position in case of enable is at `true`. There are no hooks in conditions statements. Or it returns always null, or it return (in the right order) the hooks.

Comment: Hook usage cannot be optional. "eslint-plugin-react-hooks" will flag this as an issue, eg `React Hook "useState" is called conditionally. React Hooks must be called in the exact same order in every component render. Did you accidentally call a React Hook after an early return?`

Comment: `enable` actually can change and this is a problem here, like `<Component enableFunct={Math.round(Math.random())}/>`.

Comment: @lecstor It can be optional, as long as a developer is aware of aftereffects and takes care of them.

Comment: @estus hmm, ok, only the last hook used would be optional then? Docs do only mention "order" but nothing about "optional" or after-effects. Will do some searching..

Comment: @lecstor Hooks should be called in the same quantity and order for specific component instance, that's the real requirement. The documentation doesn't do a good job explaining this.

Comment: First thanks for answering and debate with me about that. The main issue is that the documentation is not really clear and that's why we open the discussion internally and then I decide to move it here.

Comment: To answer: if I use both of the solutions no errors get thrown, so that's why I start to think about how to do that following the guidelines. We wouldn't use the 'changeable ' enable like estus show in his example. It would always be a fixed boolean. We want to do this to have a reusable component that activate states only in case those are enabled. So on render phases if a hook has to be activated is going to be always activated and in the same position.